# Fuse Filesystem to communicate with FTP

Tags: ftp, filesystems, fuse

I am working on a project to create a fuse filesystem in C that communicates with FTP server(only read files not write). I have implemented getattr, read and readdir fuse functions and also added libcurl functionality to it by assuming the path it receives as arguement in the function is the URL of the FTP server. But I don't understand how to pass URL of the ftp server in command line so that fuse_main() function will be called from main function and it will pass the URL as path arguement to those fuse functions.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing will be to parse this argument as part of the arguments to your program `main` function, and then to hand it to the fuse functions. You can even keep it as a static global variable as it's probably not supposed to change. See how it's done the basic "hello" example from the libfuse examples:

https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/example/hello.c#L45

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had gone through the code before but one thing I still have doubt is that what parameters should I pass in fuse_main(). Suppose in command line, I pass                       ./a.out localhost:21 mountpoint  (suppose localhost:21 is the address of FTP server), then what should I pass in fuse_main() (argv[1] -- address of FTP server, argv[2] -- mountpoint)

Comment: This is not for you to do explicitly. You should define an `options` and `option_spec` structs and pass them to `fuse_opt_parse` as done in hello.c. This function will parse the args for you.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I understood that I need to store the URL of the FTP server in the options struct and pass them to fuse_opt_parse. What I don't understand is what would go in the path arguement in getattr, readdir and read function? Would that be the path of the mountpoint or something else.

Comment: I encourage you to modify one of libfuse's examples with all kinds of prints to get an idea of how things work. The path argument always holds the location the user accessed *inside* the mount path, skipping the mount path itself (which is regarded as the root "/"). If the mount path is /tmp/myfuse, "stat /tmp/myfuse/1.txt" will lead to getattr with path being "1.txt"